# Ruby 1.9.1 isn't recognized on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wanted to install ruby 1.9.1 instead of the older version so I ran this command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

After the install was complete, I got the following error(s):

*WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 and 
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin aren't both writable. 
WARNING:  You don't have /home/brooks/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH, 
      gem executables will not run.*

When I run "ruby -v" (without the quotes) I get the following response:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

So my questions are: 1) Why is it so difficult to install ruby, 2) How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the install was complete, I got the following error(s):

Those aren't errors. They're warnings issued by rubygems. If you want to avoid them run rubygems with `sudo` or add add `/home/brooks/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin` to your PATH variable. Or if you don't care that you can't run executables installed by gems without specifying the whole path, just ignore them.

> When I run "ruby -v" (without the quotes) I get the following response:
>
> bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Try `ruby1.9.1 -v`

Comment: Yes!  When I did "ruby1.9.1 -v" instead of "ruby -v" (without quotes) it returned this: "ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i486-linux]"  That lets me know it works.  Now, I want my system to know that ruby1.9.1 is the default... how do I do this?  I still can't use rails.

Answer (score 2):

On my Linux systems I ignore apt-get for Ruby, except for the default ruby package that goes into /usr/bin. I will load any other version, like 1.8.7-head or 1.9.1-whatever using RVM into my own space if it's just for me.

If the ruby being installed is system-wide I will use a source tarball and install into /usr/local/bin and adjust my path or the #! line in the source code to determine which version I want invoked.

In my experience Ruby is easy to install on Ubuntu or any Linux as long as I don't use the packages. I know that hurts the feelings of the package maintainers but I haven't found their fruits to be to my taste very often.

For the average user I highly recommend RVM for development and testing as you can have multiple rubies installed and jump back and forth easily by using a `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` invocation and letting RVM adjust the version I'll run against by doing a `rvm use 1.8.7` or `rvm use 1.9.1`. Or, you can run commands against each installed instance by using `rvm ruby ...`. RVM is a great piece of software and Wayne should be knighted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu, /usr/bin/ruby is ruby1.8. /usr/bin/ruby1.9 is ruby1.9 and /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 is ruby1.9.1

It's a good idea to leave /usr/bin/ruby as ruby1.8 as there may be system programs that expect it to be ruby1.8

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your alternatives for ruby. Try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

If you don't already have an option for a particular version you have installed, see this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10057489&postcount=6

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why is it so difficult to install
>   ruby

*So* difficult?

> 2) How can I resolve this problem?

Synaptic lists Ruby1.9.1 does that install okay?

Here's the [Ruby 1.9.1-p378 tarball](ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p378.tar.gz) - you could try ye olde ./configure && make && make install

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it doesn't recognize ruby - even after I install it.  If I do ruby -v it doesn't return the version of ruby, it gives me an error stating that it can't find the ruby executable.

Comment: Because the Ruby executable is `ruby1.9.1` in the Debian package. You can easily make your own `ruby` executable with a symlink.

Answer (score 0):

I used rvm [link text](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to install ruby 1.9.1 and then 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem:

1. `sudo apt-get remove ruby ruby1.9.1-full`
2. Download and decompress ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org//pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p378.tar.gz.
3. `cd ruby-1.9.1-p378`
4. `ls configure` - if there **isn't** a "file not found" error, skip to step 6.
5. `autoconf`
6. `./configure` - if there are any errors, post them in a comment.
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `which ruby` - if there is any output, do not go on.
10. `which ruby-1.9.1` or `which ruby1.9.1` - There should be output from one of those.
11. `cd` to the directory revealed by step 10.
12. `sudo ln -s <your_ruby> ruby`, where `<your_ruby>` is whichever command in step 10 produced output, either `ruby-1.9.1` or `ruby1.9.1`.
13. repeat step 12, replacing `ruby` for `gem`, `irb`, `ri`, and `rdoc`. So one might be `sudo ln -s gem-1.9.1 gem`.

If you get the same `WARNING: Installing to ~/.gem since...`:

1. `nano ~/.profile`
2. append this:

.

```
export PATH=/home/brooks/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME=/home/brooks/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

Again, if there are any errors, post them in a comment on this answer.

Comment: Maybe not appropriate given the op's familiarity with Linux?

Comment: Where does it say they are familiar with Linux? Just because they use Ubuntu does not mean they are familiar with it.

Comment: Once you've given rvm a try, you'll never want (nor need) to go through all this hassle again.